# The Average of a vector square minus the square of the vector averaged

Tags: vectors

Say I've obtained a series of 3D vectors, (**x**, **y**, **z**), with a different vector at different points in time. I want to obtain the second moment of this set of vector's fluctuations in time. This is given by:

$<$ **M** $^2> - <$ **M** $>^2$,

where **M** is the vector in 3D, and the average is over time. To me, you can solve this simply by taking:

$<$ **M** $^2> - <$ **M** $>^2 = <$ (**x**, **y**, **z** )  $ \cdot $ (**x**, **y**, **z** ) $> - <$ (**x**, **y**, **z** ) $> \cdot <$ (**x**, **y**, **z** ) $>$.

However, I have seen this solved by decomposing the vector along different Cartesian axis:

$<$ **M** $^2> - <$ **M** $>^2 = < $ **M** $_x^2 > - < $ **M** $_x >^2 + < $ **M** $_y^2 > - < $ **M** $_y >^2 + < $ **M** $_z^2 > - < $ **M** $_z >^2 $.

This is shown on page 2548 in Pitera *et al.*, *Biophysical Journal*, 2001, **20**, 2546–2555. [Paper Link](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0006349501762261).

I just wanted some clarification if this second method is correct, and I guess whether the first is also. To me, the second method is not possible as you cannot decompose $<$ **M** $>$ as they have. Less so if you then square the decomposed parts.

Thank you for any help, and apologies for any grievances about the formatting.

Comment: I think this may be more appropriate for Mathematics Stack Exchange, as this seems to be about pure maths, rather than Physics.

Comment: Try it with three vectors $(1,2,3)$, $(4,5,6)$ and $(7,8,9)$ and in doing so you should be able to answer your own question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay let's see. Note that $M=M_xe_x+M_ye_y+M_ze_z \in \mathcal{R}^3$ (note that I write $M=(M_x,M_y,M_z)^T$ since $(x,y,z)^T$ is just the position vector in $\mathcal{R}^3$ and you are looking for the vector $M$, so look at the components of this vector). Calculating the variance of $M$ gives:

$\sigma_M^2=\langle M^2\rangle-\langle M\rangle^2=\langle M_x^2+M_y^2+M_z^2\rangle-\langle M_xe_x+M_ye_y+M_ze_z\rangle \cdot \langle M_xe_x+M_ye_y+M_ze_z\rangle = \langle M_x^2\rangle+\langle M_y^2\rangle+\langle M_z^2\rangle - \langle M_x\rangle^2 - \langle M_y\rangle^2 -\langle M_z\rangle^2$ where we used that $\langle M_xe_x + M_ye_y +M_ze_z\rangle=\langle M_x\rangle e_x + \langle M_y\rangle e_y + \langle M_z\rangle e_z$ (by the rules of expectation values, you can split it out and vectors have constant coefficients) and just worked out the (standard) inner product on $\mathcal{R}^3$ between two of such vectors. Hope it helps, it is a basic question on variances in principle. Greets.

Comment: Makes sense, cheers!

Comment: Apologies, I can't upvote as I do not have 15 reputation yet - however I have marked it as the best answer